# Convert string column 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss' into a SAS date format 'dd.mm.yyyy'

Tags: sas

I need to write a script that converts symbolic data to data format. I have a table with column `date`, containing strings like `28.01.2017 09:23:14`. I need to convert them to a date format `28.23.2017`. 
i tried:

```
data SMS_STAT;
    set SMS_STAT;
    date = input(date, DDMMYY9.);
    put date = DDMMYY9.; 
 run;
```

Also, i tried diffrent formats in `date` and `put`, but that didn't help: it converts to a `.`

I have substringed `28.01.2017 09:23:14` to `28.01.2017` so now, i want to make a date from it.

Comment: You have syntax issues.  1) those back quotes will cause trouble 2) argument 2 to the INPUT function the format requires a dot as DDYYMM9.

Comment: Hi Vladislav. Please clarify context of issue. Is it a script? I can't catch. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VitaliyPro Yes, this is a script

Comment: @data_null_ i fixed mistakes, could you, please, take a look again

Comment: Dates in that format take 10 characters, not 9. DD.MM.YYYY

Comment: You cannot store a number into a variable that is already defined as character. Make a new variable.

Comment: @Tom if i use DDMMYY10., it just leaves that field the same

Comment: @Tom Thanks, but i still cant format it correctly

Comment: Your question includes an invalid date string `28.23.2017`.  Is it possible you are actually asking to convert from DMY to MDY format and so meant to say `01.28.2017` instead?

Comment: @Tom You are right, sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make a dataset with a character variable named DATE with values like: `28.01.2017 09:23:14`.

```
data have ;
  date='28.01.2017 09:23:14';
run;
```

If you just want to take the date part and leave it as a string then just use SCAN() or SUBSTR() function.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  date = scan(date,1,' ');
run;
```

If you want to make an actual date variable then you need to make a new variable since dates require numeric variables instead of character variables.  You can use the INPUT() function to read the current string into a date. You can then attach whatever format you want to have SAS display the data.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  date2 = input(scan(date,1,' '),ddmmyy10.);
  format date2 mmddyyp10. ;
run;
```

If you just want leave it as a string and reverse the day and the month fields then perhaps it is even easier to just use SUBSTR() function.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  substr(date,1,5) = substr(date,4,2)||'.'||substr(date,1,2) ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, finaly, i came to this solution:

```
dates = substr(date, 1, 10);
d=input(dates,DDMMYY10.);
format d DATE9.;
```

Comment: Are you looking for the end result to be displayed as `date9.` or a `mmddyyp10.`? I think in the question you are looking for the latter. Maybe edit one of the two for consistency? Thanks...